# Can I safely install an attic ladder here?

Tags: roof, attic, ladder

I would like to take advantage of some available attic space to use as storage being that we are extremely tight on space in our old Victorian row house. My plan is to install an attic ladder and create an enclosed area by putting up sheetrock walls and laying plywood over the joists. My contractor says it is doable but I wanted to get a second opinion.

Based on the pictures and video, does this project seem feasible? I was also wondering if the vertical pieces of wood seen in the pics are needed? They seem fragile and don't appear to be doing much.

See video here: https://youtu.be/2YgG5_cZVx4

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's dangerously foolhardy to jump to the conclusion that the folks who built your house just had a bunch of lumber they didn't need, so they slapped it into the structure for no reason other than to impede your storage project 150 years later. Particularly if your "joists" are 2x2-1/8" which makes the storage *dubious at best.*

Comment: +1 to the concern about weight bearing on 2”x2” sticks. Throwing plywood up there both helps (spreads load) and hinders (adds weight). Honestly, if storage was my concern, this would rank dead last in my list of places to use.

Comment: I only asked about the vertical sticks because they seem very weak, some are hardly attached. Only thing I can think of is that they are there to prevent warping of the 2x2 joists somehow?

Comment: Don’t want to beat a dead horse, but the verticals are not your biggest problem. If you’re a cracked plaster enthusiast and absolutely must store stuff up there, just work around them.

Comment: I am a cracked plaster enthusiast! How did you know?

Comment: There is no structure up there to support a floor and storables, the "joists" are to hold up the plaster ceiling only.

Comment: I would recommend calling a couple more local contractors to get estimates for what's necessary. If you get 2 or 3 saying, "No way would I do that", or "Sure, but we'll need to reinforce the joists", then you have your answer from experienced pros who can actually get hands-on with your property. You'll also find out if your contractor is giving you a reasonable price or not.

Comment: That looks miraculous. It reminds me of the ACI's minimum steel for flexural reinforced concrete. That minimum requires enough reinforcement to carry the uncracked concrete beam's rupture load. That way when the beam cracks there's enough rebar to stop it from brittly crashing to the floor. I'm wondering if those 2×2s have the strength to carry the plaster rupturing load up there. With those high ceilings, I don't think I would go up there. If I had to, then I would inspect the space below for impaling hazards first.

Comment: Where are you? I think I'd blow in a properly modern amount of cellulose insulation and then keep the heck outta there, per the comments above.  Just... have less stuff. If it doesn't love you back, pass it on.

Comment: @isherwoodb I'm in NJ.

Comment: When in doubt, get a second or third contractor in to give you an estimate on what it would take to make this happen. Someone onsite will have a far better feel for what's going on, plus will know _your_ local codes. If the other 2 contractors say "no way, joists aren't sturdy enough", you've probably got your answer. OTOH, they might say "yup, let's rock" and you might even find a better price point!

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason that the original hatch is on one side.  It is avoid cutting the "joist".  You should also do the same.  It may look better in the centre, but you are cutting into structural timber, which is already weak by todays standards.

But if you must, then you should consult an Engineer.